# A contradiction when using condition number of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, computational-mathematics

When learning the condition number of matrices, defined as $K(A) = ||A||\cdot||A^{-1}||$, I found that there may be a contradiction about using it to judge whether a linear system question is an ill question, i.e. when $K(A)$ is a really big number, which means there may be a big error between $A^{-1}$ computed on computer and its real value, why can we believe that $K(A)$ can characterize the error of the solution of $Ax=b$?

Furthermore, I wonder whether we can estimate $K(A)$ by only using $A$ rather than $A$ and $A^{-1}$.

Comment: The fact is that it is theoretically a good index. It is used in theoretical analysis of algorithms and methods, so it does not depend on the computer you are computing it on

Comment: No contradiction. You may need special care to compute it (moreover, don't pay too much attention to the norm of $A^{-1}$: it is not in this way that it is computed in general) ; but, besides,it is a proven excellent indicator of stability

Comment: The condition number of a non singular matrix can be expressed as a derivative. It means there is some set of inputs for which the error will be large, not necessarily all. There is no contradiction.